# How do I create one CSV file containing two models with comma gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fastercsv

I would like to create one CSV file containing two models with comma gem in my ruby 3.2.8 application. Maybe the answer to the question is trivial, but this is the first time I use this gem. I know how create the file it based on a model, but I don' t know how make matches of two.

I have a views\participants\index with :

```
<%= link_to 'Download CSV', '/participants.csv' %>
```

the controller :

```
def index
 @participants = Participant.all
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @participants }
   format.csv  { send_data @participants.to_comma }
 end
end
```

participant Model:

```
require 'comma'
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  comma do
    id
    token
  end
end
```

and field Model:

```
require 'comma'
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  comma do
   name
   value
   id_participant
  end
end
```

in the db i have:

```
Participant1 = ["id" => 1 , "token" => "a"]
Participant2 = ["id" => 2 , "token" => "b"] 
Field1= ["id_participant" => 1, "name" => "p1_exams1", "value" =>5]
Field2= ["id_participant" => 1, "name" => "p1_exams2", "value" =>3]
Field3= ["id_participant" => 2, "name" => "p2_exams1", "value" =>2]
Field4= ["id_participant" => 2, "name" => "p2_exams2", "value" =>3]
```

I would like to have a file like this:

```
id   token
 1     a

id_p  name            value
 1   p1_c1_exams1      5
 1   p1_c1_exams2      3

id   token
 2     b

id_p  name            value
 2   p1_c1_exams1      2
 2   p1_c1_exams2      3
```

I tried with this in controller:

```
def index
@participants = Participant.all
@fields = Field.all
require 'csv'
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    @participants.each do |p|
        csv << ["id","token","last_ip_address","start_date","last_transition_date","completion_date","completed","total_time_survey","created_at"]
        csv << [ p.id, p.token , p.last_ip_address, p.start_date, p.last_transition_date, p.completion_date, p.completed, p.total_time_survey, p.created_at]
        @fields.each do |f|
            if String(f.id_participant) == String(p.id)
                csv << ["id","name","value","id_participant","id_survey","created_at"]
                csv << [f.id,f.name, f.insert_value, f.id_participant, f.id_survey, f.created_at]
            end
        end
    end
end


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @participants }
  format.csv  { send_data csv_string,
    :type => "text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present",
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=Database.csv" }
end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the fastercsv for this 
i think this will help u what i am understanding that u have has many relationship between Participant and Field regarding this i have write some piece of code u can customize it as ur need

```
@participants = Participant.all
  csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
     @participants.each do |i|
     csv << ["id","token"]
     csv << [ i.id, i.token ]
     i.fields.each do |j|
      csv << ["id_p","name", "value"]
      csv << [i.id,j.name, j.value]
     end
     end
     end
 send_data csv_string,
          :type => "text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present",
          :disposition => "attachment; filename=anyName.csv"
```

Comment: I try now, thanks ! but, do I put this code into cotroller? and the call of view, how it is done? in the model have to put some instructions?

Comment: You can add this to controller. Sorry i have missed some of the basic part to send the data after csv genearation now i have make changes to my solution

Comment: ehm , i've a Problem : Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library. It's FasterCSV plus support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine. But I have 1.9.3 Ruby and 3.2.8 Rails...

Comment: with 1.9 you no longer need/can use the fastercsv gem, since it's bundled in the std lib. Now you just need to do is remove the gem from the Gem file and just require  'fastercsv' inside the controller